# Date losing value when being stored

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm trying to get a set of dates into a particular format (ddmmyy) so that they can be run against a number of scripts that I have.

I have managed to convert the date into the correct format, but when I try to store this as a variable it just returns as null or the un-formatted date.

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate SMALLDATETIME

SELECT @CurrentDate = getdate()
SELECT @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, -1, @CurrentDate)
SELECT @CurrentDate = STR_REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,@CurrentDate,3),'/',null)

--Returns this:
20-Mar-2002 00:00:00
```

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate SMALLDATETIME

SELECT @CurrentDate = getdate()
SELECT @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, -1, @CurrentDate)
SELECT STR_REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,@CurrentDate,3),'/',null)

--Returns this:
020320
```

I believe the problem comes from the fact that my declared variable is a smalldatetime object but I'm not sure of how to convert it correctly into a string that can be stored as a variable?

I've tried having a second variable and declaring it as a varchar and then storing my date as the varchar but this isn't working either:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @CurrentDateFinal VARCHAR

SELECT @CurrentDate = getdate()
SELECT @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, -1, @CurrentDate)
SELECT @CurrentDateFinal = CAST(STR_REPLACE(@CurrentDate,'/',null) AS VARCHAR)

--Returns this:
03-Mar-2020 00:00:00
```

Comment: Would I still be able to minus 1 day from it if it was a string though?

Comment: There is no reason for it to be a string from the beginning then really, I just thought it was easier as I knew I would need to use the DATEADD function.

Comment: That's what I'm doing above though isn't it? I've tried creating a second varchar variable but this is the one that gives me null as my output instead of any date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208967/discussion-between-bobybobp-and-unhandledexcepsean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the current date amendment with the dateadd all in one line - there's no need to do two lines. The below gives you the DDMMYY output although I wouldn't use that format personally as you can come unstuck with regional differences (e.g. US prefer MMDDYY and UK tends to be DDMMYY). Also always use 4 digit years IMO.

```
    DECLARE @FirstDate SMALLDATETIME
    DECLARE @FinalDate varchar(20)

    SELECT @FirstDate = DATEADD(day, -1,getdate())
    set @FinalDate = STR_REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,@FirstDate,3),'/',null)
    SELECT @FinalDate

    --------------------
    030320
    (1 row affected)
```

Comment: Thanks this works, so the solution for me was just to use SET instead of SELECT. The date format had to be as such so that the final script will accept it. I'ts only a local script so shouldn't cause problems with regional differences.